# C++: Creating an OpenCV Mat object with specified row addresses

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, opencv3.0

I am using OpenCV 3.2 on C++ and I cannot find a way to do the following task:

Suppose I have 10 pointers to `double` arrays, say `row_0`,...,`row_9`, where each array contains 20 elements. I want to create a `cv::Mat` object having 10 rows and 20 columns such that its 0th row starts at address `row_0`, 1st row starts at address `row_1` and so on. In other words I already have each row stored contiguously in the memory (however the entire block of 10 rows may not be contiguous) and I want to 'gather' them into a Mat object. How can I accomplish this?

Of course I can declare a 10*20 array, copy the rows successively into it and then call the `cv::Mat(int rows,int cols,int type,void *data)` constructor, but this requires unnecessary copying of the data. The matrix I need is actually much bigger than 10x20. Moreover I am needing to do this many times in my application, so copying would make my program slow.

Comment: Aside from a (constant) padding between rows, the data **must** be contiguous. You'd better re-design your program to store contiguous values, or do some memcpy